# Spring-Boot: Dependency Injection depending on the configuration (and using interfaces)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, architecture

I have the following question regarding the structure of my application architecture.
Assume my application consists of the following components

First of all a **@ConfigurationProperties**, which initializes my needed properties (here only a type to select a provider).
In addition, a bean of the type "**Provider**" is to be registered at this point depending on the specified type. This type is implemented as an **interface** and has two concrete implementations in this example (**ProviderImplA & ProviderImplB**).

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Profile("provider")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "provider")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "provider", name = ["type"])
class ProviderConfiguration {
    lateinit var type: String

    @Bean(name = ["provider"])
    fun provider(): Provider {
        return when (type) {
            "providerA" -> ProviderImplA()
            "providerB" -> ProviderImplB()
        }

    }

}
```

Next, only the two concrete implementation of the interface.

```kotlin
class ProviderImplA: Provider {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var serviceA: ServiceA

}
```

```kotlin
class ProviderImplB: Provider {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var serviceA: ServiceA
    @Autowired
    lateinit var serviceB: ServiceB
    @Autowired
    lateinit var serviceC: ServiceC

}
```

And last but not least the interface itself.

```kotlin
interface Provider{
    fun doSomething()
}
```

**Now to the actual problem or better my question:**
Because my concrete implementations (ProviderImplA and ProviderImplB) are no valid defined beans (missing annotation e.g. @Component), but they have to use their own @Service components, it is not possible to use @Autworie at this point. I would like to avoid different profiles/configurations if possible, therefore the initialization by property. How can I still use the individual @Service's within my implementations and still create the provider beans manually, depending on the configuration (only one provider exists at runtime)? Maybe you have other suggestions or improvements?

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating objects directly, spring cannot control its life cycle, so you must create an @Bean for each 'Provider'

```
@Bean(name = ["providerA"])
@Lazy
fun providerA(): Provider {
  return ProviderImplA()
}

@Bean(name = ["providerB"])
@Lazy
fun providerB(): Provider {
   return ProviderImplB()
}
```

IdentityProviderConfiguration class

```
IdentityProviderConfiguration {
  var context: ApplicationContext
  ...

  fun provider(): Provider {
    return when (type) {
     "providerA" -> context.getBean("providerA")
     "providerB" -> context.getBean("providerB")
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: But the thing is, only one provider can exist at the same time and this provider should be selectable from outside via the configuration.

Comment: I adjusted the example

Comment: Okay, thanks. But how can I solve the situation that my implementations have to use/depend on other beans/configurations?

Comment: When we research the context, spring will take care of the dependency tree

Comment: Oh okay. So I can keep the @Autowired Annotation inside the Implementation Classes?